# How to have the xlim with seaborn automatically adjust based on dataframe date range

Tags: loops, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to loop through plots. Each "station" is a pandas dataframe has a single water year of data (oct 1 to Spet 29). The data is being read in with this code:

```
sh_784_2020 = pd.read_csv("sh_784_WY2020.csv", parse_dates=['Date'])
sh_784_2020.columns = ["Index", "Date", "Temp_C","Precip_mm","SnowDepth_cm","SWE_mm","SM2","SM8","SM20"]
```

My plots loop through but the x-axis always starts at the year 2000 through the current date displayed but my data is from 2006-2020. Is there a way to have the xlim adjust automatically for the date range in the data frame? Or is there a way to create this plot in matyplotlib and not seaborn?

```
for station in stations:
    station['Density'] = station['SWE_mm']/(station['SnowDepth_cm']*10)*100
    station['Density range'] = pd.cut( station['Density'], [-np.inf, 25, 30, 35, 40, np.inf])
    Date =  station.loc[:, 'Date'].values
    SWE_mm =  station.loc[:, 'SWE_mm'].values
    Density =  station.loc[:, 'Density'].values
    sns.scatterplot(station['Date'], station['SWE_mm'], hue='Density range', data= station, edgecolor = 'none', palette=['grey', 'green', 'gold', 'orange', 'crimson'], alpha= 1)
    plt.xlim ()
    plt.show()
```

Plot example 1
[image]
Plot example 2
[image]

Comment: It's much easier t osolve these problems if you can provide a minimum reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upgrade to seaborn 0.11 you should find that the default autoscaling works better, but you can get a good result without upgrading by creating the `Axes` object before plotting and setting the units, e.g. something like

```py
ax = plt.figure().subplots()
ax.xaxis.update_units(station["Date"])
```

Comment: I upgraded seaborn and it fixed the issue without having to add code! Thanks